# How to use @FindBy for driver.findElements(By.xpath()).size>0

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Currently I am using @FindBy annotation for an element as below

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@class='fNiv' and contains(text(), 'Home')]")
public static WebElement Tab_Home;
```

But when I try using Boolean I am getting an error "Change to getSize()" and my Boolean syntax is

```
//AllGeneralTabs is the class name where I have stored my elements
Boolean home=AllGeneralTabs.Tab_Home.size()>0;
```

I want something to work in such a way when I define my Element as

```
public static final By Tab_Home=By.xpath("//a[@class='fNiv' and contains(text(), 'Home')]");
```

then the Boolean will work perfectly for the below syntax

```
Boolean home=driver.findElements(AllGeneralTabs.Tab_Home).size()>0;
```

It returns true/False and works as expected but this is not happening for @FindBy annotation. As I defined all my elements using @FindBy now and I cannot go back and change it to final statement, I don't have time.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below solutions.

```
@FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@class='fNiv' and contains(text(), 'Home')]"))
List<WebElement> allElements;
```

OR

```
@FindBys(@FindBy(xpath="//a[@class='fNiv' and contains(text(), 'Home')]")))
List<WebElement> allElements;
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks... now am able to identify the elements without any error

Comment: "how = How.XPATH," what does this do? i'm trying to find online resources but i found them confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing between `WebElement` [size](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getSize--) witch return `Dimension` and `List` [size](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()) witch return `int`. You didn't say what exactly you are trying to do, but it seems you are looking for

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@class='fNiv' and contains(text(), 'Home')]")
public static List<WebElement> Tab_Home;
```

Comment: Yeah am looking for this. Thank you